# konva: Is there a way to tune parameters for `tap` event?

Tags: touch, konvajs

In my konva app, users are having trouble tapping on icons ... frequently konva issues a `dragStart` event instead of a `tap` event (presumably due to the length of time the user's finger is down or the fact that their finger moved slightly during their tap).

Is there a way to tune the parameters for wait time and/or movement distance under which a `tap` will be issued?

I see that there is a `dragDistance` which postpones issuing a `dragStart` until the user has moved the given number of pixels, but I haven't found a way to tell it to issue a `tap` event under a given number of pixels.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, your question is not 100% clear for me. But I think `dragDistance` can fix your issue. Some value around 5-6 works very good.

Comment: Ah, interesting ... upon further testing, I see that I was mistaken.  For the most part, konva will indeed issue a `tap` event for movements less than `dragDistance`.  However, one of my objects has stopped issuing them for regular taps.  However, if I pound on it 2-3 times in rapid succession, I will still get a `tap` event.  Meanwhile, my stage responds to taps exactly how I would expect.  Does behavior like that ring any sort of bells with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ... it turns out that in our app, we were disabling the hit graph on our layer on `touchstart` and as a result, the intersection test returned a different object on `touchend` than on `touchstart`, so it properly did not register a `tap` event.

So, all is well with konva.  :o)

Just don't disable your hit graph on `touchstart`.  ;o)